# How can we access value from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lodash

Suppose we have an array like:

```
let arr = [
  [{
    values: [{ 
      name: 'sumit sharma'
    }]
  }]
]
```

How can we print it without a loop or without `arr[0].values[0].name`?

Is there any lodash function or any other way?

Comment: 1) What exactly do you mean by 'print it'? 2) What's wrong with looping or accessing by index?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan writing code like <h1>{arr[0].values[0].name}</h1> looks complax or not clean

Comment: So what's the issue with that line of code?

Comment: What if there are more elements in any of those arrays?  Generally, you'd map over them displaying each element, and extremely rarely would you only care about arr[0].

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  is there any another way to access this value

Comment: If you want just that one value, then not really. I'm sure there's libraries you could use for prettier syntax, but that's entirely redundant for one line of code. If you want to get multiple values in the array, then there's nothing at all wrong with a forEach loop

Comment: i just want that one value

Comment: Than loading a ~25Kb JS library to remove ~20 bytes of text is pointless.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to visualize it on a browser, you can just use `console.log(arr)`
[image]

Comment: thank you but no need to visualize

Comment: How is this even relevant to the question? anyone knows how console.log works